# Will my RAID configuration be preserved after BIOS upgrade?

Tags: cpu, bios, raid, upgrade

I have a setup build on "ASRock Z690 PRO RS" oat the mother board I have 3 RAIDs:

- Raid1: 2X NVMe SSD (system)
- RAID5: 3X HDD 9TB
- RAID5: 4X HDD 9TB

Right now I want to make an update to 13th Raptor gen but this operation require a BIOS update.

I am afraid that if I flash new BIOS then all my configurations will be gone. I am also afraid that if I flash new BIOS and try to manually set up same RAID as it was before, then during the new configuration, the system will force me to format all discs and I will loose all data.

I can not backup data (it is too big). Preserving the data is really important as it is surveillance footage that is crucial for the company I work for.

- My current BIOS version: 1.31
- BIOS that I want to install: 15.03

Comment: 1) Can the surveillance data be reviewed and deleted where possible, such that the amount of data is reduced to something that can be backed up? 2) If you haven't been given the budget to back it up, it cannot be that important. 3) You should work on the basis that the RAID arrays and data will be lost, even if you backup the BIOS settings so that you can restore them after a BIOS update.

Comment: 4) If it ain't broke, don't fix it.